# how to make my app work in background in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I developed an app in UWP [a background feature] like a timer sound.  Every 5 seconds a sound plays automatically.  In debug mode everything works OK, but in release mode with a disconnected USB, the background sounds do not work. What should I do?  I found in the `package.appxmanifest` tab Declarations a background task, is the solution here?

Comment: [Support your app with background tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks).

Comment: how?, i can't do that with myself i need help :)

Comment: If you cannot read and comprehend technical documentation, I'm afraid, your only option is to hire a developer that can.

Comment: i need to use In-process background task. can you help me?

Comment: What does ''in release mode with a disconnected USB" mean?

Comment: i connect my Microsoft mobile 640XL with USB and i install my app in my phone and disconnect USB from my Phone and run app to show what i do, i found my app don't work in background like a debug mode with connect USB everything work well.